# Jquery removed element registers click but loses parent data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my case, when you click an **.error** class, it is removed `.remove()`. But there is also a function that registers click *outside* a **.select** class. When the **.error** class is inside the **.select** class, and the **.error** is clicked, the jquery registers a click *outside* when it is actually *inside*. The problem occurs from the elements removal. `.remove()` takes with it all the parental information which is needed to find out if there was click *inside* or *outside*. How can I call `remove()` after without merging both functions?

I want to remove the **.error** but also for it not to register a click outside `.select`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="select">
  <div class="error">Error: Click here</div>
  Select Zone
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("click",function(event){
 if(!$(event.target).closest(".select").length){
  alert('this alert will go off but its inside .select class element?');
 }
});
$(document).on("click",".error",function(event){
 $(this).remove();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bv7vkw90/2/

Comment: You may want to stop the event propagating when you call remove: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: Did you try the @EvanTrimboli's solution?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I can't use event.stopPropagation() because it disables other important functions. :( but thanks